# Windows 7 Update Driver Software for all hardware

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I downloaded all of the drivers for my dell and placed them in a folder on my c drive. I would like to update all of the drivers without going one by one.

Is there a way that I can Update the driver software for all devices through a script or something?

Comment: For the most part you can simply use the generic default device drivers unless there is a specific oem driver only feature you wactually want.  It will take exactly 5 minutes to install those drivers, if you really want them installed, I suggest you just get it over with.

Comment: I forgot to add that i know about the dell product that scans the system and downloads drivers. it seems i must live with doing it one by one

Comment: Are you asking because you have many of the same computer you need to do this with?  If so, there are options for creating custom installation media, creating a Windows image, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Dell Support website will try to download and install all drivers if you allow it. Just go there and ask it to analyze your system, it will find new drivers and you just click Install.

If that is not working and you really need to download them manually, I'm afraid there is no way to automate it (in a way that would be useful in the future, as opposed to just wasting more time with scripts than manually doing it once). The .exe you downloaded are auto-extract zip files and there each one has a different Setup.exe with a different workflow.

Additionally, some generic drivers might be updated by Windows Update if they are included by default. So run Windows update, check the Optional Updates and then go to Dell.com and check for new drivers. I believe this is the most efficient way for a single machine.